# Which is the django url regex for a token as a parameter?

Tags: python, regex, django

I want to activate my users in my django server when they follow a link from their email with a token, like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/user-activation/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImdhYm8iLCJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxOSwiZW1haWwiOiJsYXRvcnJlZ2FiQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsImV4cCI6MTQ2NDE3ODk1N30.5FDKdxKxWuOkqe3rMNE-eHwmtrlWpD7EZ-EXw0yQM3U/
```

I have this pattern

```
 url(r'^user-activation/(?P<id>\w+)/', views.UserActivation.as_view()),
```

But it's returning 404. I searched a lot and nothing seems to work. What am I doing wrong?

I couldn't find any answer that works reading

https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/urls/

nor

https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/http/urls/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your token also includes `.` and `-` characters so you need your regex to match them also - it currently will only match word characters

```
url(r'^user-activation/(?P<id>[\w\.-]+)/', views.UserActivation.as_view()),
```

Comment: No need to escape `.` in a character class. To make it more obvious, change the order to `[-.\w]`.

Comment: @Jan - Sure that works too, but I've had to work with developers before that edit code without understanding it so I like the security provided by escaping the dot :)

Answer (score 4):

`\w` in python regex will match any alphanumeric character and the underscore; this is equivalent to the set `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. You had all kinds of characters like `.` and `-` that don't match, it's bound to fail.

You need `[\w.-]` to include them.

Check python doc on [regex syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).

Comment: See the comment in @Sayse's answer - no need to escape the dot in a character class.